# Como Cancelar una peticion JSONObjectRequest Android Studio

Tags: volley

Tengo un problema al hacer una petición usando Volley, resulta que luego obtener la respuesta y de procesar esa respuesta y guardarla en mi DB local en el dispositivo, la petición se vuelve hacer, que esta sucediendo? Y tengo un muchas peticiones dentro de una clase en mi proyecto de android y esto sucede con tres de esas peticiones..
Gracias de Ante mano...

P.D.: En todas las peticiones dentro de esta clase, le tengo a todas la politicas de reintento de conexión al WebService, por que donde estoy la conexcion a internet es supremamente lenta